# PHP Files - Downloading instead of Loading in Browser?

Tags: php, download

I have this file, index.php. I FTP'd it to my web server. When I go to the page mydomain.com/index.php my browser downloads the php file instead of loading the page.

The only code in the php file is `<?php echo "hello world;" ?>`.

Why isn't the page loading as intended?

Comment: are you sure your web server supports php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP installed on the server already, you should ensure that Apache recognizes it by configuring httpd.conf properly.

Answer (score 1):

The server most likely doesn't have PHP installed.

Answer (score 0):

This occuers becase of web server . your  web server think php files like text files or pdf files . you should install a program for your web server to interpret php files.

sorry I was not logged in before :)

Answer (score -1):

This occuers becase of web server . your  web server think php files like text files or pdf files . you should install a program for your web server to interpret php files .